# Indentation in nxml-mode in GNU Emacs

Tags: emacs, xhtml, indentation, nxml

Here is an example how XEmacs makes indentation in xml-mode of a xhtml document:

```
    <div><a id="page_1"/>
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
```

in nxml-mode in GNU Emacs it looks like this:

```
    <div><a id="page_1"/>
    <p>text</p>
    </div>
```

This is the result of auto-indentation which belongs to indent-line-function.
I also know the possibility to avoid this behavior by writing the closing a-Tag to a new line. But this appearance I use is necessary for my workflow.

Have somebody any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: Is that the result of `indent-region`, or merely of pressing return?

Comment: Looks like an Emacs minor bug with an easy workaround: don't put several elements in the same line (at least don't do that if one of them is opening and the last is closed).  For a proper permanent solution I would suggest reporting a bug to emacs maintainers.

Comment: @juanleon Thank you for your suggestion for reporting a bug, I'll do it. I've updated the description of my problem.